# Alternative printing method(s) for an unsupported printer

Tags: server, software-recommendation, drivers, windows, printing

I have in my office, a Konica Minolta bizhub 211 multifunction printer, it works well with windows workstations... It has a lot of good features, like duplex...

[image: konica minolta bizhub 211]

I haven't found any drivers for UNIX, so I'm looking for alternative methods, how can we make it useable in Ubuntu. I'm thinking on some windows based server, or what I know...

It's id in `lsusb`: 132b:2052

I wrote here requesting for drivers: [ubuntu.hu](http://ubuntu.hu/node/21191), [linuxforums.org](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/hardware-peripherals/170483-konica-minolta-bizhub-211-driver.html#post809237), [forums.debian.net](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=56152#p325906), [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1590592); and also to the manufacturer, but they said only, that *"the first PostScript supported printer is only bizhub 223"*, so they don't care that thing.

**Update**: I've heared about the raw printing method trough a normal Windows workstation. Have someone got any information about this workaround?

Please suggest working methods,

Thanks, B. Roland

Comment: Just a stab in the dark but have you checked with wine I heard something about ddiwrapper being a possibility as well.

Comment: i only say To find out the device ID of your printer, connect to USB then typing lsusb in a terminal window will list all USB devices on your system. Try to find the relevant line for your printer. The ID then appears after "ID" on that line, in the form xxxx:xxxx where the 'x's are numbers or letters and then try to goggle it for that ID

Comment: @Allan thanks, but they say, that is only for Canon printers...

@hhlp, ok, I'll look it up, thanks!

Comment: No answer/solution, but a hint if it applies to the 211 BizHub, as it does with some other models: sometimes these types of printers have SMB shares, so that documents scanned from the workstations are saved on the printer share. When files exist in the printer share, the printer then queues them up to be printed. (Drag-and-drop to accomplish printing.)

Comment: @hhlp, it is 132b:2052 and I haven't found anything...

Comment: Update about the raw printing.

Answer (score 3):

Once your unsupported printer is recognized either from USB or if setup as network printer from the appropriate network setting you are asked for a driver. If your printer is not listed you can alway select "Generic" to give you a choice of standard printing methods depicted below:

[image]

In this example on the left hand side a "PCL6/PCL XL Printer" is selceted and gives you again a variety of selections of PCL6 subsets on the right hand side. Depending on your model your Konica/Minolta printer may be a PCL6 printer and this entry may work, but you will have to simply try out what subsets are appropriate. If it's not PCL6 you may also try out if a generic GDI driver works.

Fancy special things your printer may be capable of will not work with a generic driver but at least you can print out something.

Comment: :( I've tried every GDI & PCL6 and it doesn't prints :(

Comment: @B. Roland: sorry to hear that. The bizhub is a GDI printer that comes with optional PCL6 interface. So at least it should be able to be addressed using a generic GDI driver. What interface is your printer attached to, USB or Ethernet? Was the printer detected by CUPS? Any error messages?

Comment: I tried only with Ethernet, the Printer Configuration Tool is detects the printer in network, it shows no error messages; When I send a Test Page, it shows: "Test page sent to printer(jobid: X)". And then it is not printing...

Comment: CUPS generic GDI may not support the bizhub 211. You may try with the bizhub 160 GDI Unix driver ppd support from [KonicaMinolta](http://onyxftp.mykonicaminolta.com/download/SearchResults.aspx?productid=851) hoping the GDI specs did not change too much. If that fails also - hmm - send a postscript-printed file to a Windows workstation and print from there?

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't solved my problem :( I also tried to download the kmpu(Konica Minolta Printing Untilities) but it also fails :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Seems this printer is not suported by CUPS - blame Konica. Cant't think of any other way than sending a postscript-printed file to the windows hosted driver in this case. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is a method I used to print to a non-linux friendly Lexmark.  It should work with any Windows printer.

### What you need

1. You'll need a a PC or a Virtual Machine running Windows on the same network.
2. Make sure your printer can print from your Windows PC/VM
3. Download and install [Ghostscript, GSview](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/GPL/gpl864.htm) and [RedMon EE](http://www.is-foehr.de/) onto your Windows PC

### Configuring Windows Printing

Using `Printers and Faxes` - File - Server Properties, Add a new port and select "Redirected Port".  The ports on the server should update with `RPT1: Redirected Port`

### Install a Linux Friendly Printer Driver

Still on windows:

- Add a printer that is recognised by both Ubuntu and Windows e.g. "AppleLaserwriter 16/600 PS".
- Set it to print to local port "RPT1: Redirected Port"
- Configure the port with the values

`C:\Program Files\Ghostgum\gsview\gsprint.exe`

for the "Redirect this port to the program" and

`-printer "Windows Printer Name" -copies 1 -`

for "Arguments for this program are:"

- Share this Printer for Everyone to use

N.B. "Windows Printer Name" is the name of the Windows printer in `Printers and Faxes`

### Setup a Print Connection to Windows

In ubuntu - add a Printer - connect to the Windows printer and use "AppleLaserwriter 16/600 PS driver"

You can now print to the "AppleLaserwriter" printer.

Note - this will take quite a while for large documents since the Windows PC will need to convert from AppleLaserWriter format to Ghostscript and finally convert this into your other Windows printer format.  Its wise to use a fairly speedy PC!

Comment: Oh thanks, very nice tutorial. In the future I'll try it out! I have a WinXP installed to a VirtualBox, I'll use bridge network, and it must work.