# How do I get my Kodak printer to work?

Tags: 10.04, printing

I have a Kodak ESP C310 printer that I tried installing on my computer (Ubuntu 10.04), but it wouldn't even recognize the device.  So, I went on the Kodak site and talked to a representative online (after Googling and not finding anything helpful), and all they told me was that Kodak drivers do not support Linux or any form of Linux, like Ubuntu.  I asked them if they ever would, and the person told me they were working on it.  Well, that doesn't help me at all.  Has anyone been able to work around this problem of Kodak not supporting Linux?  I don't want my printer to go waste, I need it.

Thanks!

Comment: The only alternative I can think of is to use a Windows machine - physical or virtual, together with a method such as I described in this question and answer:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/25015/alternative-printing-methods-for-an-unsupported-printer/54231#54231

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've said, Kodak don't currently distribute Linux drivers for their machines, but the internet is a vast place, and, thanks to the amount of more advanced users using Ubuntu, their are some available.

They are not official, nor are they overly tested, but they do sometimes work.

Unfortunately, there are known bugs with the C Series printers. Fortunately, you can download and install for free, [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cupsdriverkodak/).

The project is called **c2esp**, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have that model printer.  I use google cloud printing.  I save the file as a .pdf and e-mail it to the printer's cloud address.

Answer (score 0):

The work-a-round I've used to print from my Ubuntu linux system to my Kodak ESPOffice 2170,
is to set up "eprint" on the 2170.  The setup process creates an email address of the form
@kodakeprint.com.  When you email to that address it will:
1) print the email
2) print any attachment (MS Office) or pdf file to the printer.

Michael Valley

Answer (score 0):

Lucky me, the *Kodak Verite' 50 Eco* I just bought at Walmart has DL-able drivers for Linux Ubuntu and Debian on the official support site.

http://www.funaihelp.com/kodak/printer/downloads

I chose the Ubuntu 64bit package (despite it saying it was for distro 14.04 LTS). It DL'd a .DEB package, and all it took was a doubleclick on the DL'd file in the Download folder to launch and install. I then brought up the bottom left corner Menu, Applications, Administration, Printers and set up a new network printer. The rest was easy and intuitive. Test page successfully printed.

OS: Linux Mint 18.1 MATE