# Kodak ESP C315 Printer

Tags: printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get my Kodak printer to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75542/how-do-i-get-my-kodak-printer-to-work)

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 by replacing my Windows Vista, I am finding really difficult to install Kodak ESP C315 all-in-one-printer. Both printer and scanner not working.   I could not be lucky enough to find any help online and apart from some help with few computer codes. To me it seems impossible to find out the solution as I am not programming expert.

Comment: You have to install driver for Kodak ESP C315 Printer. Download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cupsdriverkodak/files/c2esp24.tar.gz/download).
Extract all files. Check out Install and Read me file for installation.