# How do I get an Advent AW10 Printer working?

Tags: printing

Has anyone managed to get any of the Advent AW series printers working with Linux? Advent support states

"All-in-one printers do not support LINUX OS at this time.

The all-in-one printers are designed to work with WINDOWS XP, WINDOWS VISTA, and WINDOWS 7 Operating Systems and with MAC OS 10.4.8 or higher."

I wish I had read their website before purchasing the thing!

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Advent like Kodak (the technology the advent printers are based on) have never and maybe will never developed Linux drivers for their ESP printer series.

However there is some effort from the community to provide some printing functionality. But this will likely to be not of the extend a Windows driver will offer.

There is a sourceforge project providing [CUPS drivers for Kodak printers](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cupsdriverkodak/). On their page they claim some support for the AW10 as well.

> - And in the Cxxx series: AdventAWP10 Hero 9.1

We were unable to test this and thus cannot provide an installation guide but it may be worth a try.

Comment: Choosing `KODAK HERO 9.1 AiO` from the list of available printer drivers works for me in 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly if you look at your installation disks there may be a PPD file which you can use when setting up your printer driver:

[image]

An alternative suggestion would be to connect it to a windows computer or virtual machine guest running windows and use [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25015/alternative-printing-methods-for-an-unsupported-printer/54231#54231) to print to this non linux friendly printer.