# Where can I get drivers for a Lexmark X5150 printer?

Tags: printing, lexmark

Where can I find the proper drivers for a Lexmark X5150 printer? I don't have an internet connection on this computer.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 or 10.04?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst Lexmark has begun to support linux with a few of their current printers, unfortunately they did not produce one for [your particular model](http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=EN&page=product&userlocale=EN_US&productCode=LEXMARK_X5150&focusedTab=DOWNLOADS#3).

This was discussed over at [linux mint](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=71540)

> Lexmark X5150
>
> Does this printer work with free software?
>
> No. If you are able to purchase a new machine, buy an OfficeJet, or a
>   suggested printer.
>
> Another possibility is to configure for several different lexmark
>   printers, and hope that one works. Like a lottery.
>
> Does Lexmark have drivers for this machine?
>
> No. Their binary driver set does not support it.
>
> Does scanning work?
>
> No. You'll definitely have to write a driver yourself.

If you have your PC in a small network containing a Windows PC you could use a technique such as I described in [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25015/alternative-printing-methods-for-an-unsupported-printer) to print to it if the printer was attached to the Windows PC.

Comment: Even though my printer is Linux supported I can't download the Linux driver from their support page.  There is a compatibility list for the printers as published by [Lexmark](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&id=OS4).  Problem even with that list is that most of these are 32-bit only. :(

Comment: the x5150 is not on the list... what is your printer?

Comment: I have X6675.  Here is the [driver](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&actp=DD_LIST&productCode=LEXMARK_X6675&id=DR20523&os=UBUNTU_9.04&oslocale=en_US&segment=DOWNLOAD&userlocale=EN_US&locale=en)

Comment: ok - that's worth a new question - something like "how do I install a 32bit printer driver in 64bit ubuntu vxx.xx"

Comment: I actually just submitted one.  Made me realize that the main reason I ran a 32-bit OS is no longer there. :)